# Android SeekBarListener in a different class

Tags: android, seekbar

When a seekbar is changed. Where is the listener activated?

EX:

```
ClassA
{
    ClassB myClass = new ClassB(); 

}
ClassB
{
   SeekBar mySeekBar = new SeekBar;
}
```

If the seekBar is in classB. Can I have the listener in ClassA ? Or do I have to have it in ClassB and toss a flag back to ClassA?

My goal is to tell ClassA how much the progress is on ClassB's seekbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener can be anywhere you want. This is why you have a *setOnSeekBarChangeListener()* to register it. That class listening should extend *SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener*, and pass it to *setOnSeekBarChangeListener()* for that given *SeekBar*.